# Another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I faced with this error `The instance of entity type  cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked` when saving model in ASP.NET Core.

Quick solution not work: **My DbContext isn't singleton**. Also, I face with this error only on one model, saving other works correct.

#### This is my Repository saving method:

```
 public class EFRepository:IRepository
 {
    private DatabaseContext dbcontext;

    ...

    public void InsertOrUpdate<T>(T entity) where T : AbstractModel
    {
        costil_logging(entity);

        if (entity==null) throw new NullReferenceException();

        if(dbcontext.Set<T>().Any(x=>x.ID==entity.ID))
        {
            //Update
            dbcontext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; //ERROR HERE
        }
        else
        {
            entity.ID = 0;
            dbcontext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        }

        dbcontext.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

#### This is my Repository initialization:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services.AddScoped<IRepository, EFRepository>();
  ...
}
```

#### This is my model:

```
public class Section:AbstractModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsMedicalSection { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get { return this.categories ?? (this.categories = new List<Category>()); }
        set { categories = value; }
    }

  public virtual ICollection<PriceCategory> PriceCategories
    {
        get { return this.priceCategories ?? (this.priceCategories = new List<PriceCategory>()); }
        set { priceCategories = value; }
    }
```

#### And here is my controller save method:

```
    [Route("section/edit")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditSave(Section section)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            repository.InsertOrUpdate(section);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
        }

        //Errors displaying
        return View("Edit",get_error_model(section));
    }
```

### What kind of problem it can be?

Comment: Please don't put tags into Question Title. We spend much time fixing this all the day and have less time for answering questions. stackoverflow.com/help/tagging And don't use wrong tags neither. ASP.NET is for the legacy ASP.NET 4.5, not for ASP.NET Cor

Comment: I suspect because you are not attaching your model. In your code, you are fetching the object(s) in `dbcontext.Set<T>().Any(x=>x.ID==entity.ID)` but don't save it's result anywhere. I think this causes your entity to be tracked if found (if not, the else will work correctly because nothing is found). When you call Entry it tracks this object by reference, but since your object is not the same as the one you track you get the error. Try attaching your model before changing its state

Comment: Like `dbContext.Set<T>().Attach(entity)`, then `dbcontext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;` after it has been attached

Comment: `Attach` didn't help. I have same error on it. Strange, that other models is saved correctly, but they are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you load the object twice, that s why you are having this problem.

Make sure you register your repository once per HTTP request, this ensure that you a single instance of your db context and it tracks the object once.

Comment: I using dependency injection my Repository to controller in constructor and create DbContext in a constructor of repository. Is is correct?

Comment: There are three modes you can use in DI: Singleton (one per application), Scoped (one per Request) and Transient (one per resolve). DbContext should be resolved by scope, unless you are exactly knowing what you're doing (i.e. you want an explicit control over the life-time and know how to do ensure its not accessed multiple times per request :P)

Comment: I use scoped injection: `services.AddScoped<IRepository, EFRepository>()`. And Controller's constructor called every request. So, I have an instance of dbcontext per request, but I'm still having this error